# Update dataframe name in python within the for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am writing a for loop in python and would like to do:

```python
for i in range(11):
   resulti = defined_function(dfi)
```

So, I can get `result1`, `result2`, ..., `result10`.

Basically, I'd like to apply the same function to 10 different data frames (`df1`, `df2`, ..., `df10`) quicker than manually applying it one by one.

Comment: You could simply create a list named `df` of DataFrames, and call them `df[0]`, `df[1]`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#globals) with[`eval`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#eval) :

```
for i in range(11):
    globals()[f"result{i}"] = defined_function(eval(f"df{i}"))
```

*NB: This assumes that the variables/dataframes (`df1`, `df2`, ..) are defined before the loop.*